# Analytic Applications of Stone-Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, compactness, compactification

Following Bredon's *Topology and Geometry*, we let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all continuous maps $f:X \to [0,1]$ on a completely regular space $X$, define $X \xrightarrow{\Phi} [0,1]^{\mathcal{F}}$ by setting $\Phi(x)(f)=f(x)$ for each $x \in X$ and $f \in \mathcal{F}$, and declare the closure $\beta(X)$ of $\Phi(X)$ in $[0,1]^{\mathcal{F}}$ to be the *Stone-Čech compactification* of $X$. Munkres writes in *Topology* that there are "a number of applications [of the Stone-Čech compactification] in modern analysis", which is purportedly "outside the scope of [the] book." I looked at a few sources, including *The Stone-Čech compactification* by Russell Walker, and failed to find any application of the theorem that is overtly analytic. Perhaps I do not have sufficient background in functional analysis---this is where, I assume, the prototypical analytic applications would be in--to recognize the functional-analytic applications I have encountered, but the point remains that I have yet to *see* such an example. So:

> What are prototypical applications of the Stone-Čech compactification in mathematical analysis, and where can I read about them?

Comment: I think the most important analytic applications of ultrafilters are [ultralimits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit) and Banach limits (in guise of [invariant means on amenable groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable%5Fgroup)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what Munkres is talking about, but here's something he *could* be talking about. Let $X$ be a completely regular space and let $C_b(X)$ be the ring of bounded continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$. This is a commutative [Banach algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra) when equipped with the sup norm, and in fact it is a [$C^{\ast}$-algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2A-algebra) when equipped with the trivial involution.

Then the [Gelfand spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation) of $C_b(X)$ is canonically isomorphic to $\beta X$; equivalently, $C_b(X)$ is canonically isomorphic to $C(\beta X)$. One application here is that by the [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_linear_functionals_on_Cc.28X.29), positive linear functionals on $C_b(X)$ can be identified with Borel regular measures on $\beta X$. A special case of this construction is described in the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone-Cech_compactification#An_application:_the_dual_space_of_the_space_of_bounded_sequences_of_reals).

Comment: I've added link to the wikipedia article. (I hope this is the one you had in mind.)

Answer (score 6):

Stone-Čech compactification is frequently mentioned in the book Carothers: [A short course on Banach space theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=pec4r3EsIiMC&pg=PA148&dq=carothers+stone+cech), so this might be a good guess where to look for such applications.

One of the applications is Garling's proof for Riesz representation theorem for $C(K)$, $K$ being compact. The proof is first done for the Stone-Čech compactification of discrete space and then extended to arbitrary compact Hausdorff spaces.

You can check Chapter 16 of Carother's book, or some of the following papers:

- D. J. H. Garling: [A ‘short’ proof of the Riesz representation theorem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100077021), Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 1973 - Volume 73, Issue 03, pp 459-460
- D. J. H. Garling: [Another ‘short’ proof of the Riesz representation theorem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100064173), 
  Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 1986, Volume 99 / Issue 02, pp 261 - 262
- Donald G. Hartig: [The Riesz Representation Theorem Revisited](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975760), The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 90, No. 4 (Apr., 1983), pp. 277-280
- One of these papers mentions that this proof can also be found in the book R. B. Holmes: [Geometric functional analysis and its applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=vDXvAAAAMAAJ).

I am making this post community wiki, so that if someone is more familiar with the proof, they can add more details. (I only know that such a proof exists and more-or-less understand what are the basic ideas behind it.)

Comment: The proof of Riesz theorem is mentioned also here: [Proofs of the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270275#1270384).