# Proofs of the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, compactness, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $C(X)$ the set of all real continuous functions on $X$, and $\mathcal{B}$ be the Baire $\sigma$-algebra of $X$, which is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the functions in $C(X)$. Furthermore $M(X)$ is the set of all finite signed measures on $(X,\mathcal{B})$ with the norm $||\mu||=|\mu|(X)$, $|\mu|$ being the total variation of $\mu$. Finally, for all $\mu \in M(X)$ define $\phi_{\mu}:C(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\phi_{\mu}(f)=\int f d\mu$.

It is possible to formulate the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem as follows:

The application $\mu\mapsto \phi_{\mu}$ is a surjective isometry from $M(X),||.||$ onto $C(X)^{*},||.||_{*}$ the dual space of $C(X),||.||_{\infty}$.

In other words the topological dual of the Banach space $(C(X),||.||_{\infty})$ (with as usual $||f||_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in X} f(x))$) can be identified with $M(X)$.

My question is: since there is a functional analysis formulation of the theorem, is there a functional-analysis-flavoured proof of it ?

Note that this version of the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem is much stronger than the usually stated one, which is concerned positive functionals on $\mathbb{R}$. The fact that the dual norm is the total variation one is equivalent to the fact that Baire measures are necessarily regular, a not so trivial fact proved in Halmos's *Measure Theory*.

I find proofs like the one in Rudin's *Real and complex analysis* disturbingly artificial and complex for such what seems such a natural and important result: an integral is nothing more or less than a bounded linear functional on continuous functions (when integrating over a compact space).

I had a professor who used Daniell's integral with which the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem follows almost instantly. That is a very good proof, the best I've seen so far, but I'm still under the impression that there might be other ways to look at the problem.

Comment: (just adding a link: I came here from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258844/alternative-proof-of-a-theorem-of-riesz)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My favourite proof is due to Hartig:

> D. G. Hartig, [The Riesz representation theorem revisited](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2975760?uid=3738032&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106302962861), *American Mathematical Monthly*, **90**(4), 277–280.

Hartig claims that his proof is ...category-theoretic but having unwrapped the details I must say it is really functional-analytic. The idea is as follows.

- Step 1. We can easily prove this theorem for [extremely
  disconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space) compact Hausdorff spaces. Indeed, everything can be
  reduced there to messing around with indicator functions of clopen subsets.
- Step 2. We employ the [Stone–Čech compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of a discrete
  space. One can use the Banach–Alaoglu theorem to show that every completely
  regular space admits the Stone–Čech compactification. The Stone–Čech
  compactification of a discrete space is extremely disconnected.
- Step 3. Now, we prove that every compact space $X$ is a continuous
  image of an extremely disconnected space. Indeed, give $X$ the
  discrete topology. Call this space $X_d$ and extend the identity map
  $\iota \colon X_d \to X$ to a continuous map from $\beta X_d$ to $X$.
  Then, transfer the Riesz theorem to $X$ via the adjoint map to $f\mapsto f\circ (\beta\iota)$ ($f\in C(X)$).

Comment: The proof is due to Garling, Hartig is only giving an exposition.